# 2 ways of installing a ruby gem

Tags: rubygems, installation

As far as I know, there are 2 ways of installing a ruby gem to the application, which are installing on the command prompt and using Gemfile. What is exactly different between them?

**On the commnad prompt**

```
gem install font-awesome-rails
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `gem install` only installs it on your local system. Your application won't have that dependency when you deploy it to your remote server--without it being on the gemfile, your deployment's buildpack won't know what to install.

Here's a bit more on what happens when you deploy on heroku, you'd do similar things if you're deploying using Capistrano. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks